# Probem to install psycopg2

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm trying to install psycopg2 with `pip3 install psycopg2` and getting this error

```
It appears you are missing some prerequisite to build the package from source.

You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI.
If you want to install psycopg2 from source, please install the packages
required for the build and try again.
```

after this I runned `pip3 install psycopg2-binary` but still getting this error

I tried to run `sudo apt install python3-dev libpq-dev` and returned:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-dev is already the newest version (3.8.2-0ubuntu2).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpq-dev : Depends: libpq5 (= 12.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but 13.2-1.pgdg20.04+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I'm improving my English, be patient.

Comment: What is the exact error you get when you do `pip3 install psycopg2-binary`. I find it hard to believe it is the same as installing the source version.

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: psycopg2-binary in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (2.8.6) ------> I expressed myself wrong

Comment: That just means it already installed. Go ahead and use it.

Comment: but when i try to run `pip3 instal psycopg2` is giving me the same error.

Comment: You don't need to install it, `psycopg2` is already installed. Open a Python session and try `import psycopg2`

Comment: Ohh, ok, thx man

Comment: have any difference in the binary version?

Comment: This is what the docs are for, see here [Install](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html#quick-install).